# Payment method not display in admin order detail

Tags: payment-methods, migration, magento2.3.2

Magento Version 2.3.2
After Migration authorise.net payment method did not displays in Admin Order.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually, after debuging, I found the real problem which is data is different in the table when we place the new order its response data is different than old data which migrated.